# jhipster - convert byte array to image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

> I have images on machine of server. I want to retrieve image and display it in UI using angularjs.
>   I convert image to byte array in RestController. In angularjs, I send a request to get byte array then display byte array as an image in html. But image do not show on web page. Below is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/images", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getProductImage(String fileName) {
    byte[] result = null;
    File serverFile;
    try {
        serverFile = productService.getProductImage(fileName);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(serverFile);
        // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        result = (data.getData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName);
    HttpHeaders headers = null;
    if (mimeType != null) {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(mimeType));
    }    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Base64.getEncoder().encode(result), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

> angularjs

```
vm.getByte = function(fileName){
      $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/api/images',
          params: {
              fileName: fileName
          }
      }).success(function(success){
          vm.imgFile = success;
      });
    };
```

> html code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Image</label>
<div class="form-group has-avatar" ng-if="vm.Product.productImg">
  <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{vm.imgFile}}" style="width: 200px;height: 130px;" />
```

> current result:
>   [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f8Zp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should fix code in java follow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/images", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getProductImage(String fileName) {
    byte[] result = null;
    File serverFile;
    try {
        serverFile = productService.getProductImage(fileName);
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(serverFile);
        result = Base64.getEncoder().encode(IOUtils.toByteArray(fi)); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName);
    HttpHeaders headers = null;
    if (mimeType != null) {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(mimeType));
    }    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```